# Beginner Angular JS app, interpolation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, controller

I just started with Angular JS (version 1), and not been able to get the interpolation running correctly. I already checked it with solved versions, and looks fine to me. I even placed a console.log inside controller and its not printing anything. Please help.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" np-app="LunchCheck">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Lunch Checker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      .message { font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: bold; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container" ng-controller="LunchCheckController">
       <h1>Lunch Checker</h1>
       <div class="form-group">
           <input id="lunch-menu" type="text"
           placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch"
           class="form-control" ng-model="food">
           Content is: {{food}}
       </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('LunchCheck', [])

  .controller('LunchCheckController', LunchCheckController);

  LunchCheckController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function LunchCheckController($scope){
    console.log("In controller");
    $scope.food = 'Enter something';
  }

})();
```

Comment: you have written  np-app="LunchCheck" instead of ng-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace np-app by ng-app it will work

Answer (score 0):

You've written np-app instead of ng-app

`<html lang="en" np-app="LunchCheck">`